# Vue.js : How to use id to select an item in another array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got 2 array, one for states and another one for countries. I want to display the country name of the state. So, I'm using Laravel 5.7 for the backend and I get data using this for the countries `Country::get();` and Vue.js recieve the array like this:

```
countries:Array(4)
    0:created_at:(...)
        deleted_at:(...)
        id:(...)
        name:(...)
        shortName:(...)
        updated_at:(...)
    1:{…}
    2:{…}
    3:{…}
```

I do the same for the state as the country.  `State::get();` and vue recieve this:

```
states:Array(1)
    0:country_id:(...)
        created_at:(...)
        deleted_at:(...)
        id:(...)
        name:(...)
        shortName:(...)
        updated_at:(...)
```

When I display the data into the table using v-for:

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="state in data.states">
        <td>{{SOMTHING TO DISPLAY COUNTRY NAME}}</td>
        <td>{{state.name}}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

At the first cell, I tried to do `{{data.countries[state.country_id]['name']}}` but it failed. Instead it display another country in the array where the key correspond to the country_id I gave.

I know that I can solve my problem by doing this `State::with('country')->get();` and then into my vue component doing this `state.country.name`, but since I already send every country, I'm looking for another way to perform it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `JOIN`your country data to your state data using `state.country_id` mapped to `country.id`.

## Map your countries by ID

```
const cmap = {} // in your vue.data
countries.forEach(it=>cmap[it.id] = it)
```

Or use reduce

```
const cmap = countries.reduce((acc,cur)=>{acc[cur.id]=cur; return acc},{})
```

## Put the map in a computed property so it is calculated one time on demand.

```
countryMap(){
    return this.countries.reduce((acc,cur)=>{acc[cur.id]=cur; return acc},{})
}
```

## Create a lookup method

```
getCountryName(state){
    return this.countryMap[state.country_id].name
}
```

## Use it in a template like this

```
<div>{{getCountryName(state)}}</div>
```

You don't *need* a lookup method, but if you are using Vue, it makes sense to break things up. `this.countryMap[state.country_id].name` is a bit messy in a template.

Comment: Thank you, this work like a charm. I did some change to adapt to vue.js. I used your reduce function as a computed property ```countriesMap: function() {
                return this.data.countries.reduce((acc,cur)=>{acc[cur.id]=cur; return acc},{});
            }``` then I just have to use the computed property like you did in the lookup ```{{countriesMap[state.country_id].name}}```. When I create a country, it add it to the map and if I create a state without reloading, it display the country name as well! Big thank you!!!

Comment: @ElieMorin using map as computed is a GREAT idea.  You got it!

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using map with many object, I just changed my code in a way that I don't need to repeat myself everytime.

Since now, the code is a method instead of a computed property.

```
dataMap: function($model) {
    return this.data[$model].reduce((acc,cur)=>{acc[cur.id]=cur; return acc},{});
},
```

I use it this way into the component:

```
{{dataMap('countries')[dealer.country_id].name}}
```

And my data look like this:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            data: {
                countries:{...},
                states:{...},
                cities:{...},
                groups:{...},
                dealers:{...},
                users:{...},
            },
        }
    },
```

So that way I can use the dataMap method for anything found into data array without having to recode a new map computed property. I just have to do this:

```
{{dataMap('users')[something.user_id].field}}
{{dataMap('groups')[something.group_id].field}}
```